# How to apply conditional number format?

Tags: qt, qml, number-formatting

With this `modelData.amount.toLocaleCurrencyString()` I get:

```
+---------+---------+
|  Input  | Output  |
+---------+---------+
|  100000 | 100,000 |
| 1000000 | 1e+06   |
|  -10000 | -10,000 |
|       0 | 0       |
+---------+---------+
```

Why do I get scientific notation for numbers above 999,999? This actually isn't that useful for me. What I need is conditional formatting like `#,##0;(#,##0);-` that puts negative in parentheses and converts `0` to `-` in addition to normal comma separators for positives.

I also don't want currency symbol in my numbers.

Comment: what type is `modelData.amount`? use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format the float value with  fixed-point notation

Comment: @folibis, it's int.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible out of the box, looking at (Qt doc)[ https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-number.html#toLocaleString-method]. You should probably add a ternary operator and type your different output formats manually